# Как с помощью ffmpeg проверить поврежден mp4-файл или нет?

Tags: linux, shell, видео, ffmpeg, centos7

При склейке нескольких видео иногда попадаются поврежденные файлы, после которых ffmpeg прекращает свою работу. Файлы он берет из txt-файла. Как можно с его помощью проверить поврежден файл или нет и, если файл поврежден, то просто пропустить его и не добавлять в txt-файл, чтобы в дальнейшем ffmpeg даже не смотрел на него?

Comment: Ответ вроде бы уже есть: [check-the-integrity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077302/quickly-check-the-integrity-of-video-files-inside-a-directory-with-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого можно попросить декодировать файл в ничего.

```
ffmpeg -v error -i example.mov -f null -
```

Для исправного файла эта компанда не покажет ничего. Для неисправного - покажет кучу ошибок на stderr. Например:

```
$ ffmpeg -v error -i example.mov -f null - 2>&1 | cat
[mpeg4 @ 0x55d32a585e80] I cbpc damaged at 1 5
[mpeg4 @ 0x55d32a585e80] Error at MB: 231
[mpeg4 @ 0x55d32a591d80] Error at MB: 3572
[mpeg4 @ 0x55d32a595440] Error at MB: 3423
[mpeg4 @ 0x55d32a59f780] Error at MB: 3542
[mpeg4 @ 0x55d32a5ad180] Error at MB: 2670
[mpeg4 @ 0x55d32a585e80] P cbpy damaged at 43 79
[mpeg4 @ 0x55d32a585e80] Error at MB: 3677
```

Определённое неудобство здесь в том что ffmpeg не выходит с кодом ошибки, а значит были ли ошибки можно узнать только посмотрев на вывод. Не составляет труда написать скрипт который будет это делать хоть для одного, хоть для кучи файлов. [Пример.](https://superuser.com/a/100290/16120) [Ещё пример.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34088828/93540)

Comment: проверил ваш пример: написал небольшой скрипт с условием. оказалось то, что надо. спасибо большое за ответ. это поможет игнорировать поврежденные файлы.